# Cant Find Template Error

Tags: templating, error

I'll start with I know very little about CraftCMS...inherited this project.

Seems to run well except recently I started getting these types of errors (see below). Secondly the CP assets and users template is failing to load as well. This site runs fine on my local so to me this seems like a server-side config/permission/phpversion change, or other unknown. Looking for some advice on the next dart to throw in the dark.

Now I know that the twig template is where it suppose to be so HIGH LEVEL I'm wondering if this might be:

A: a server permission error
B: an issue related to not being able to delete template caches, ongoing issue...not new.
C: A configuration/pathing error
D: PHP version?

Thanks.

```
2017/05/03 15:55:11 [error] [exception.Craft\TemplateLoaderException] Craft\TemplateLoaderException: Unable to find the template “includes/form.twig” in "_includes/contentForm" at line 4. in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php:124
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php(71): Craft\TemplateLoader->_findTemplate('includes/form.t...')
#1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(329): Craft\TemplateLoader->getCacheKey('includes/form.t...')
#2 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(419): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('includes/form.t...')
#3 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/TwigEnvironment.php(61): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('includes/form.t...', NULL)
#4 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(366): Craft\TwigEnvironment->loadTemplate('includes/form.t...', NULL)
#5 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/cc/cc123f4b69c51ba3fb7d9a9861bd34437019eacc365672a70bf4ea69a27b24b1.php(25): Twig_Template->loadTemplate('includes/form.t...', '_includes/conte...', 4)
#6 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_01e2c4fb75ed16e13ebab562be51ae878262c1c316da8ebac5ab1cf5c1b1c5d5->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#7 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#8 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#9 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/04/04571408200886c7c8a1ae5274dc8ada4f8868211b12b92f88f7abc22b0c6b58.php(77): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#10 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_2850f15379d843d4d4159e608a63b953c20aba41a24472fc1c618f9f4afc8207->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#11 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#12 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#13 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/d0/d006f55a12c6c25b1df60cf1a426983bb01fefee03ba3a0e705203ec06f38c1d.php(81): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#14 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_21662d3a280988e89b845244e1f7457af5d47e90ea3a8f22303bb25043233eb7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#15 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#16 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#17 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/d9/d9c3c424852ea1ab2234ec77778ef25c91518f55e4515e1fd41c204af998bdbf.php(45): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#18 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(215): __TwigTemplate_bdc32da372629fcf2061f0342a9ac87c3e2b31dbcd154cf621cdf95f11fe451a->block_content(Array, Array)
#19 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/7b/7b10b73c0ddd653bd4e5e10f379a8c5efeda3cdaae3c26cee53bdf82a5e6e2e9.php(144): Twig_Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#20 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_a17739a24f825c66b435cebb05405edfb372b8288d9ac218a4ae3563234ad0cb->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#21 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#22 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#23 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/d9/d9c3c424852ea1ab2234ec77778ef25c91518f55e4515e1fd41c204af998bdbf.php(24): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#24 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_bdc32da372629fcf2061f0342a9ac87c3e2b31dbcd154cf621cdf95f11fe451a->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#25 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#26 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#27 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#28 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(362): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#29 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(256): Twig_Environment->render('pages/index', Array)
#30 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('pages/index', Array)
#31 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php(68): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('pages/index', Array)
#32 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('pages/index', Array)
#33 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Array)
#34 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#35 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#36 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#37 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#38 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('render')
#39 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#40 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(290): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#41 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#42 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#43 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/boisedotorg/public/index.php(19): require_once('/srv/users/serv...')
#44 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/media-room
```

Comment: If you go to yoursite.com/media-room, do you get a similar error?

Comment: Do you really have an `includes` directory, and an `_includes` directory? You're currently trying (and failing) to load `includes/form.twig` from `_includes/contentForm`.

Comment: @BradBell landing on media-room has a FORMERLY plugin form, page throw 'Internal Server Error Unable to find the template “includes/form.twig”...Now I agree the log file states form.twig should be loaded from contentFORM..

Comment: ContentForm looks to path {% include 'includes/form.twig' with { form: theForm } %} which doesnt exist..specifically form.twig lives right next to contentFORM.twig under _Includes, what befuddles me is why would this pathing be off assuming no edits. We recently did a template replace from localhost but that wouldnt have changed those pathings(?)...will change path and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

To followup and close. It was a 'typo' or rewrite of the include path for this issue. Forms work fine now.